# Mathematics for Graduate Political Science

Tags: soft-question, applications, advice

I'm preparing to attend graduate school for political science here in Canada and I'm having something of a crisis. Midway through my degree program I chose to drop my first love (English) to focus on what I was more interested in professionally. I'm now completing a honours degree in political science and international relations. Thing is, I've lost much of my quantitative ability (not that I had much to begin with). I was able to do some differential calculus a couple years ago, but I fear I've forgotten much of what I knew how to do.

I've become fascinated with quantitative methodology and want to practice quantitative research in graduate school. I'm currently on track to study theory. So here's my question: If I want to be able to use quantitative methods in grad school (say negative binomial regression, for example) how much math should I know prior to entering? Multivariable calculus? Linear algebra? Differential equations? When it comes to eventual knowledge, the sky's the limit, but I'm immediately concerned with applied maths. Pardon any ignorance inherent in this post.

Comment: Do the places you want to study at not have a list of requirements to study your area of choice? To be honest, I think a much better place to ask this question would be to look at Academia SE (http://academia.stackexchange.com/), or to just contact someone attached to the graduate program you're thinking of doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For quantitative social science, the more math you can learn before you get to grad school, the better. A minimal preparation would be something like:

- Three semesters of calculus, which is usually two of single-variable and one of multi
- One semester of linear algebra
- One semester of probability and statistics

If you have time, the following courses would look good:

- Differential equations
- Advanced probability or mathematical statistics courses
- Real analysis, which might be called advanced calculus

Topology also couldn't hurt, in case you want to learn functional analysis later on. You should *certainly* take a couple of computer science courses.

Comment: Nice list. Do you think game theory should be included?

Comment: I thought about mentioning game theory, yeah. It would be optional, to be sure, not in the core.

Answer (score -1):

The standard list of maths needed are as follows:

1) A "good" calculus class this is at the level of MITOCW calculus or edx.org calc 1A, calc 1B, calc 1C etc.   Free or 49 dollars if you want certificate

2) Linear Algebra say MITOCW linear algebra by Gilbert Strang  free

3) Econometrics try MITOCW econometrics or coursera.org econometrics  free or 49 dollars

4) Bayesian Methods try coursera.org Bayesian Methods UC Santa Cruz  free or 49 or more if you take 5 course series

5) Software Learn how to use R and Stata at a minimum

6) Learn how to clean a data set

7) take the survey methodology series on Coursera at least 4 courses 49 each or free

8) Don't take any more than this without doing some serious reading of political science journals.   If you can't read the journal with
 understanding as in being able to replicate the analysis

9) Work for a politician or sit and watch at local senate/house meetings
10) read some partisan mags./radio shows/  etc.

11) Learn the language of political sci don't apply to you know the area break down of all the areas of political science American, Political Economics, Methodology, etc.

12) more important to know the language of political science and to have an imagination of how to write about it than to be have math phd so don't overdo the math.

13) Don't forget to sit in on some classes at your local phd mill.

14) coursera.org Game theory I & 2 stanford and Tokyo Uni Intro game theory

15) Network Theory class coursera.org or edx.org

16) Model Thinking Coursera.org

17) You shouldn't need Grad real analysis, Measure theory, Functional Analysis, Topology, etc.

18) You might need Control theory if dynamic models is an interest.  But read the journal first because if you don't like those types of papers or if no one really does them why should you.

Comment: Game theory is not optional if you can take it before and you can coursera.org Stanford Game theory 1 and 2 are free   and at grad school level except you don't have to do a paper after the class (what a shame).